# Read only certain parts of string/line PHP

Tags: php, fgetcsv, file-read

I have a file(.txt) that has the following format:

> DOE,JOHN K              V00008483028 FB               1444.00
>   1444.00         1444.00                                                        DOE,JANE HAHN           V00008475645 FB    6579.00   -6579.00

I need to find a way to extract just the part from each line that has the account number ie. V0000....  There are no delimiters in the file, so that is what is making it difficult.

Comment: read each line and check if the string is there using strpos or regex

Comment: Can you edit the question to use code formatting to show the file contents? Indent each line with four spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will the format always begin with `V0000`? If so this will work and store the results in a simple array. If not the regex can be modified to suit your needs e.g. `'/(V\d+)/`.

```
$str = file_get_contents('./file.txt');
$matches = [];
preg_match('/(V0000\d+)/', $str, $matches);
$matches
//=> [
//=>  "V00008483028",
//=>  "V00008483028",
//=>]
```

Answer (score 2):

Spaces can be used as delimiters:

```
$line  = "DOE,JOHN K V00008483028 FB 1444.00 1444.00 1444.00";
$lineParts = explode(" ", $line);

print_r($lineParts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
explode(' ', $line)[2]
```

^- This will yield **"V00008483028"**

But **only** if you use the exact amound of spaces for each line. If John Doe had a middle name, this would not work. There is no good workaround in this scenario. You would then have to use a different delimeter, like `|`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex to extract account number :

```
preg_match('^V/[0-9]{12}/',$line,$matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
```

assuming account no has 12 numeric digits in it

Answer (score 0):

You could parse with str_getcsv parse line by line. Moreover its return by array.
Detailed information: [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
$csvString = 'DOE,JOHN K V00008483028 FB 1444.00
1444.00 1444.00 DOE, JANE HAHN V00008475645 FB 6579.00 - 6579.00 ';

$rows = str_getcsv($csvStrin, "\n"); //parse the rows 
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $val = str_getcsv($row, ";"); //parse the items in rows 
    if (strstr($val[3], 'V0000')) {
        //found V0000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is this one . Hope this will help you

```
$file = "file.txt";
$f = fopen($file, 'rb');
$found = false;
while ($line = fgets($f, 1000)) {
    if ($found) {
       echo $line;
       continue;
    }
    if (strpos($line, "V00008") !== FALSE) {
      $found = true;
    }
}
```